# How to automatic logout only using LocalStorage after 4 hours?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, logout

My problem is that I don't know where to deal with the conditions for automatic logout.
I'm using localStorage to save information about the logged-user.

At the moment someone log in, i add expiredTime object to localStorage with user information.

expiredTime like this

```
if (userEmail.includes(values.email)) {
     if (userPassword.includes(values.password)) {
       let expiredTime = new Date()
       expiredTime.setMinutes(expiredTime.getHours() + 4)
       const loggedUser = users.filter((user) => user.email === values.email)
       const addTimeToUser = {
         logUser: loggedUser,
         expired: expiredTime,
       }
       saveDataToLocalStorage('loggedUser', addTimeToUser)
       history.push('/')
     } else {
       alert('Password is not right.')
     }
} else {
    alert('Email is not right.')
}
```

After moving to '/' url, if the expiredTime is earlier it will be deleted

```
useEffect(() => {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedUser'))
    // console.log(new Date(data.expired))
    if (new Date(data.expired) < new Date()) {
      localStorage.removeItem('loggedUser')
    }
}, [])
```

But the problem with this method is that the value of localStorage is removed after a refresh. Is there any way to remove it without refreshing it?

Any advice is welcome. Thank you for answering the question.

Comment: Do you know of the `setTimeout` function?

Comment: can you try to clarify what you are trying to accomplish. `Is there any way to get rid of it without refreshing it?` doesn't make sense to me in context of logging out a user. Are you trying to reset the localstorage value?

Comment: @Evert Does that mean put 4 hours in the second parameter of setTimeout?

Comment: @Jay0813 yes, you put in a number that corresponds with when you want to run the function.

Comment: @depperm I need to keep refreshing to check the conditions in useEffect, but I want to remove  localStorage without f5. I am not good at English sorry

Comment: @Evert I haven't thought about it, but I think it'll be a good solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: You haven't `validate` expire time. In production, a user can access localStorage and change `expireTime` to forever and never have to log-in again. You can add a function to check if `expireTime` is ahead more than 4 hours from current `Date` or not.

Comment: @HuyPhạm I've never thought about that. Thank you for your advice. I'll have to think about what you said and write the code.